# excel vba code for complicated filtering

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following dataset:

```
Name   Code   Output  Type

Alice  Apple   -100    B
Alice  Apple   +60     S
Alice  Banana   -52    S
Alice  Apple    +40    S
Alice  mango   -5000   S
Bob    Kiwi    -500    B
Bob    Kiwi    +500    S
Bob    peach   -40     S
Dan    Banana   -50    S
Dan     peach  +28     S
```

I want to reduce this data using the following criteria:

1. IF records with a given name do not contain "B" in any record in column "Type" then I don't want to consider it. So the "Dan" records are out. Of the 5 Alice records, the first one has a "Type" "B" and Bob has a "Type" "B" as well.
2. For others, I want to see which fruit numbers don't net out to zero.

So this is what I would like to see:

```
Name   Code   output  Type
Alice  Banana -52      S
Alice  mango  -5000    S
Bob    peach     -40   S
```

Right now, First I am doing a SumIfs over Name and Code.

```
   =SUMIFS($C$2:$C$21,$B$2:$B$21,B2,$A$2:$A$21,A2)
```

Then I create a column where I give the value 1 when type = B and 0 otherwise.

```
 =IF(D2="B",1,0)
```

Then I am doing a Sumif to figure out which names have a "B"

```
 =SUMIF($A$2:$A$21,A2,$F$2:$F$21)
```

Then I will filter the ones which don't have a B and where the SUMIFS are not zero.

Right now this is in-sheet. I intend to use these formula in a VBA macro. Is there a better way to do this? Say without creating new columns?

Comment: Shouldn't `Alice` be out too, since it does not contain `B`?

Comment: @Shiva The first row of my data has Alice with a "B". I need to edit my question to say that the "type" (4th column) should be "B"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your columns are in the correct order as above. the below code will generate a new 5th column with 0, 1.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub SetFilter()
    Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Sheet1
    ' YOU MUST add reference "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" from tools menu to use this object...
    Dim FruitSums As New Scripting.Dictionary ' key = name of fruit, value is running total
    FruitSums.CompareMode = TextCompare
    Dim iR As Integer
    Dim lbl As String
    Dim value As Variant
    'get fruit sums
    For iR = 2 To sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        lbl = sh.Cells(iR, 2)
        value = sh.Cells(iR, 3)
        If IsNumeric(value) Then
            If FruitSums.Exists(lbl) Then
                FruitSums(lbl) = FruitSums(lbl) + CLng(value)
            Else
                FruitSums(lbl) = CLng(value)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ' calculate the filter column
    For iR = 2 To sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If sh.Cells(iR, 4) = "B" Then
            sh.Cells(iR, 5) = 1 ' ok, is a B
        Else
            lbl = sh.Cells(iR, 2)
            If FruitSums.Exists(lbl) Then
                If CLng(FruitSums(lbl)) = 0 Then
                    sh.Cells(iR, 5) = 0 ' not ok, is total 0
                Else
                    sh.Cells(iR, 5) = 1 ' ok, is not 0
                End If
            Else ' this case should not occur
                sh.Cells(iR, 5) = -1 ' unexpected output.
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```